# Rightmost node in left subtree Java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I am trying to point to rightmost node in left sub-tree in a binary tree.I am using java. I keep getting null pointer exception. And root.lchild is not null, I keep getting null even for a tree having 3 levels
Following is my code;

```
Node rightmost;
rightmost=root.lchild;
while(rightmost.right!=null)
        {
        rightmost=rightmost.right;
        }
```

Comment: You should also check if `rightmost.right` is not `null` before assign it.

Comment: 1. `root` can be `null`; 2. `root.lchild` can be `null`.

Comment: After your edit, you should not have a problem (assuming that `root.lchild` is not `null` as you state).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
Node rightmost = root != null ? root.lchild : null;
if (rightmost != null)
    while (rightmost.right != null) {
       rightmost = rightmost.right;
    }
}

if (rightmost != null) { // root or root.lchild is null
    // found
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well. But won't this point to the right child of rightmost node rather then pointing to the rightmost child itself?

Comment: If there's always a value different than `null` for `rightmost`, then the `while` loop will be infinite. Otherwise, if it's `null` at some point, the next `if` statement has no sense at all...

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Is it Ok now?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Well.. it's another simple `if`. The main thing in the question is about the cycle, I guess. Anyway, fixed.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Already added.